# LINQ Confusion - Database not persisting after the application closes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq

I'm making a WinForms app in C#.  When I go to create my database object, I'm presented with two options:

- Local Database
- Service-based Database

All I want is a simple local database to use for my project.

However, if I select "Local Database (Compact Edition)" then after I create my tables and drag them over to a LINQ-To-SQL Class creator it says:

> The selected object(s) use an unsupported data provider.

So, I don't know why creating a local database would be considered an unsupported provider when dragging to tables to the Object Relational designer.

So, I try the second type, "Service-based Database".  I lay out my tables how I want for my basic application and make my tables.  The LINQ-To-SQL Designer works fine when I drag these tables and I proceed to write my code in my app to insert and upate the database entries.

However, with this second "Service-based Database" my inserts and updates work as long as the application is running.  However, once I close it it reverts back to what it was before.  If I manually add in data via the Server Explorer it persists but any inserts I do don't save.

Why can't I create and use a Local Database with LINQ?

If that isn't an option, then why isn't the "Service-Based Database" (whatever that is), persisting beyond the application closing?

Thanks for your time!

---

Edit:  Apparently the LINQ-To-SQL Object Designer doesn't work on Compact Edition Local Databases. It can still be done, but you have to use SqlMetal apparently to generate the dmbl file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compile, the old database gets erased and a new one is copied to the bin folder. Therefore try link (using linq) to the database in the bin folder. Try change your connectionString.