# SQL table getting deleted by itself in local db, using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I wanted to try out LINQ to SQL in my new project involving movie organization. I have a local sql database with one table.

The table is a Movie table with 3 simple columns: ID, Title, Year

I populate the table by iterating over a directory, extracting data, and using InsertOnSubmit, if I check the contents of the Movie table, it appears to populate fine:

```
        foreach (var movie in movieList)
        {
            Movie newMovie = Mapper.MapMovieFromModel(movie);

            try
            {
                if (!db.Movies.Any(m => m.IMDbId == movie.IMDbId))
                {
                    db.Movies.InsertOnSubmit(newMovie);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I then have a button that loads a DataGridView from the Movie objects in the database:

there is a global myMovies list:

```
    List<MovieModel> myMovies = new List<MovieModel>();
```

and this is the code that sets the datasource:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MediaDataContext db = new MediaDataContext();

        List<Movie> movies = db.Movies.ToList();

        foreach (var movie in movies)
        {
            myMoviesHash.Add(movie.IMDbId);
            myMovies.Add(Mapper.MapMovieToModel(movie));
        }

        db.Dispose();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = myMovies;
    }
```

but then after i close the application and check the database, all the records are gone! this is literally the only code involving db retrieval.

Comment: What about `db.SaveChanges();`?

Comment: oddly enough it says "MediaDataContext does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges'

Comment: Really? That seems odd, is it a `DbContext`?

Comment: I believe so, all I did was follow this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384396.aspx, I have a Media.dbml node, a Media.mdf node, and MediaDataSet.xsd node in my solution explorer now

Comment: Interesting, I've never used that approach before.

Comment: Is there a better way to set up linq to sql? and it appears to be inserting the data properly, it all just randomly gets deleted when I close the application

Comment: Is it inserted into the SQL properly? Have you verified that?

Comment: Yep, after i hit the button that triggers the first section of code I posted, I have checked the database in ssms and the data is inserted properly

Comment: Found your answer, methinks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790228/linq-confusion-database-not-persisting-after-the-application-closes